# Elisp - Changing directory in shell buffer

Tags: shell, term

I want to open an instance of a terminal emulator (in my case `term`) and go to a specific directory, all with a single Elisp function. My idea was to send a specific string programmatically to the shell, telling it to change to a specific directory. But I don't know how I should do it, and I've not been able to find an alternative (like sending the `cd` command as the shell is opened).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to let-bind the `default-directory` when opening `term`:

```lisp
(let ((default-directory "/path/to/desired/directory/"))
  (term "/bin/sh"))
```

Comment: An elegant and functional solution! Thank you!